# how to render only one template instance in meteor

Tags: templates, meteor

Hi I have the following template :

```
<template name="users">
<ul id="item-list">  
   {{#each trackedUser}}
    <li id="{{_id}}"> 
        <span class="name">{{mUsername}}</span>
        <p><span class="description">{{mDescription}}</span></p>  
    </li>  
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

With this helper :

```
Template.users.helpers({
  trackedUser: function() {
    var curs = TrackedUser.find();
    users = curs.fetch();
    return users;
  }
});
```

The problem is that in this case for each new user, all the users are being reput in the dom.

Is there a better way to write this code so that for each new user only the

```
<li id="{{_id}}"> 
            <span class="name">{{mUsername}}</span>
            <p><span class="description">{{mDescription}}</span></p>  
        </li>
```

is redrawn ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid using `fetch`. When you use `fetch()` you don't pass along a cursor to handlebars so it can't re-render only the portion which has changed.

```
Template.users.helpers({
  trackedUser: function() {
    var curs = TrackedUser.find();
    return curs;
  }
});
```

For the case of anywhere else on your template (not in a loop) you could also use [Reactivity Isolation](http://docs.meteor.com/#isolate) which is wrapping your content in `{{#isolate}}..{{/isolate}` blocks.